# Use another directory as .vim

Tags: vim

I am working on a plugin for Vim, and sometimes I have issues, that can't be reproduced with my plugin set. I would like to get users `.vim` and `.vimrc`, but I don't want to replace/move my files.

I want to know if it possible to set another directory to be used as `.vim` and another file as `.vimrc`?

Comment: You might be able to set the `runtimepath` before launching vim and change the first thing to a different `.vim` directory. I don't know how well it would work.

Comment: I feel like the first step should be to have the other user find the offending plugin. Do this by having your user enable/disabling his/her plugins until they find offender. protip: use a binary search

Answer (score 4):

Building upon @JJoao's answer, you need to explicitly specify the `.[g]vimrc` locations, and additionally replace the references to `~/.vim` in your `'runtimepath'`:

```
vim \
-u ~user/.vimrc -U ~user/.gvimrc \
--cmd "set rtp-=~/.vim" --cmd "set rtp-=~/.vim/after" \
--cmd "set rtp^=~user/.vim" --cmd "set rtp+=~user/.vim/after"
```

Comment: Those first remove the default `.vim` directories (I assume Unix, on Windows it's `vimfiles`), and then add custom ones (again, adapt `~user/.vim` to your location).

Comment: Ah, `:set ^=` _prepends_ vs appending via `+=`; the user runtime should come _first_.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use a symbolic link for the folder.

Note that if you put `.vimrc` in `.vim` the `.` should be removed from the name: `.vim/vimrc`.

```
my:
       ln -sfn .vim myvimconf

friend:
       ln -sfn .vim friendvimconf
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I once used

```
vim -u ~otheruser/.vimrc -U ~otheruser/.gvimrc   file
```

Edit:
  This is not enough; please see @Ingo solution